# HTML5 canvas addEventListener

Tags: html, function, html5-canvas, addeventlistener

I am a beginner in HTML5 canvas.I feel hard to understand the role of a simple function's parameter.Here is the code

```
.... 
 var putpoint=function(e)
  {
     context.beginPath();
      context.arc(e.clientX,e.clientY,radius,0,Math.PI*2); 
      context.fill();
  }
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',putpoint);
 ...
```

This is a piece of code where I have my doubt.

- What does the parameter 'e' signify in above function .
- From where does the  value of 'e' comes from
- What actually the mousedown event does

I am a beginner in canvas.Please clarify my doubts.Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mousedown` is a built-in  event in Javascript that fires whenever a mouse button is pressed on an element (like a button). So by attaching an event handler to this event you can write custom code to handle the event.

Javascript also gives you an event object i.e. `e` in your case that is loaded with all the details of the mousedown event that fired, like the `e.clientX` and `e.clientY` which give the x and y - coordinates of the mouse when the event fired. There are many such properties available in the event object `e` that you can use to do cool stuff with your code.